# Best way to limit number of relational rows based on integer column in another table in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, data-modeling

I have a table for subscription plans that holds the number of license "seats" for that subscription e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE plan (plan_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, subscription_id BIGINT REFERENCES subscription "subscription_id", license_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

and currently the plan "seats" are consumed with a junction table between the plan table and the user e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE plan_license (plan_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES plan "plan_id", user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" "user_id").
```

So if `license_quantity` is lets say, 3, and there is one record in `plan_license` linking the user to that plan, there are two licenses left.

What would be the best way to ensure that the number of relation rows (licenses/seats) doesn't exceed the `license_quantity` in the `plan` table? Is there a better way to model this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not quite sure, if this is really the *best* way (it is always hard to define, it depends on many points, even what you personally define it: Performance, storage, readablitiy, maintainability, ...). I am not even sure, if I would do such "business logic" directly in the database rather than in the backend.

However, if you really want to do that, you could build a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger which will be executed before you insert the data:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2f7a7a33725c826e2669f024c7bd0d71)

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_seats() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
         used_seats int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM plan_license
        WHERE plan_id = NEW.plan_id
        INTO used_seats;
        
        IF used_seats >= (
            SELECT license_quantity 
            FROM plan 
            WHERE plan_id = NEW.plan_id
        ) THEN
        
             RAISE EXCEPTION 'Too many seats for plan %', NEW.plan_id;
    
        END IF;
    
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_seats 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON plan_license
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_seats();
```

The trigger function looks for the current seat count and throws an exception if the number of seats exceeds. In that case, the `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) operation will be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `check` constraint with custom function to achieve this requirement.

1. Write a custom function like below, which will return `Boolean` based on your condition.

```
create or replace function check_val(planid bigint) returns boolean As $$
declare
plan_qty int;
licence_qty int;
begin
select license_quantity into plan_qty from plan where plan_id=planid;
select count(*) into licence_qty from plan_license where plan_id=planid;
return coalesce(plan_qty>licence_qty,false);
end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

2. Then call it in your table's definition with check constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE plan_license 
(
plan_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES plan "plan_id", 
user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" "user_id",
CONSTRAINT check_val_1 CHECK(check_val(plan_id))
)
```

If your table already exist then you can use below query to add this:

```
ALTER TABLE plan_license 
ADD CONSTRAINT check_val_1 
CHECK (check_val(plan_id));
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=124f3d267732f9af5937b64ff9644829)